# What is the purpose of ldexp?

Tags: c++

I was wondering what people use the function ldexp() for in practical applications.

This is the description:

> Returns the result of multiplying x (the significand) by 2 raised to
>   the power of exp (the exponent).

Comment: Sounds like a bit shift...

Comment: Yeah but floating point numbers, I wonder when you need to practically use this.

Comment: Looks like a an optimisation to avoid performing floating point calculation by operating directly on the bits of the floating point number

Comment: This is an interesting related previous thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720668/fast-multiplication-division-by-2-for-floats-and-doubles-c-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ldexp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ldexp) and its dual, [frexp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/frexp), deal with the mantissa and exponent of a floating-point number.  They provide a way to get at the internal representation without doing direct bit manipulation.

Answer (score 4):

When used with `frexp` , the `ldexp` function is useful in situations that require repeated multiplication by 2. If the next multiplication causes an overflow or underflow, use `frexp` to separate the mantissa from the exponent. This gives you complete control over the exponent and the mantissa, so you can operate on them separately without any loss of precision. When you are finished, use `ldexp` to combine the mantissa and exponent again.

See more details [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc700/html/lr1/z2055681.htm).