# Slow performances of CPUs set with AVX2 in handling int and double datatypes in C++

Tags: c++, avx2

I have a strange problem with some AVX / AVX2 codes that I am working on. I have set
up a test application console developed in cpp (Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 7) with the aim of comparing the routines written in Cpp with the equivalent routine written with the set-instruction AVX / AVX2; each routine is timed.
A first problem: the timed time of the single routine changes according to the position of the call of the same;

```
void TraditionalAVG_UncharToDouble(const unsigned char *vec1, const unsigned char *vec2, double* doubleArray, const unsigned int length) {
    int sumTot = 0;
    double* ptrDouble = doubleArray;
    for (unsigned int packIdx = 0; packIdx < length; ++packIdx) {
        *ptrDouble = ((double)(*(vec1 + packIdx) + *(vec2 + packIdx)))/ ((double)2);
        ptrDouble++;
    }

}
void AVG_uncharToDoubleArray(const unsigned char *vec1, const unsigned char *vec2, double* doubleArray, const unsigned int length) {
    //constexpr unsigned int memoryAlignmentBytes = 32;
    constexpr unsigned int bytesPerPack = 256 / 16;
    unsigned int packCount = length / bytesPerPack;

    double* ptrDouble = doubleArray;

    __m128d divider=_mm_set1_pd(2);

    for (unsigned int packIdx = 0; packIdx < packCount; ++packIdx)
    {
        auto x1 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)vec1);
        auto x2 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)vec2);

        unsigned char index = 0;

        while(index < 8) {
            index++;
            auto x1lo = _mm_cvtepu8_epi64(x1);
            auto x2lo = _mm_cvtepu8_epi64(x2);
            __m128d x1_pd = int64_to_double_full(x1lo);
            __m128d x2_pd = int64_to_double_full(x2lo);

            _mm_store_pd(ptrDouble, _mm_div_pd(_mm_add_pd(x1_pd, x2_pd), divider));
            ptrDouble = ptrDouble + 2;
            x1 = _mm_srli_si128(x1, 2);
            x2 = _mm_srli_si128(x2, 2);
        }
        vec1 += bytesPerPack;
        vec2 += bytesPerPack;
    }

    for (unsigned int ii = 0 ; ii < length % packCount; ++ii)
    {
        *(ptrDouble + ii) = (double)(*(vec1 + ii) + *(vec2 + ii))/ (double)2;
    }

    }
```

... on main ...

```
timeAvg02 = 0;
Start_TimerMS();
AVG_uncharToDoubleArray(unCharArray, unCharArrayBis, doubleArray, N);
End_TimerMS(&timeAvg02);
std::cout << "AVX2_AVG UncharTodoubleArray:: " << timeAvg02 << " ms" << std::endl;
//printerDouble("AvxDouble", doubleArray, N);
std::cout << std::endl;

timeAvg01 = 0;
Start_TimerMS3();
TraditionalAVG_UncharToDouble(unCharArray, unCharArrayBis, doubleArray, N);
End_TimerMS3(&timeAvg01);
std::cout << "Traditional_AVG UncharTodoubleArray: " << timeAvg01 << " ms" << std::endl;
//printerDouble("TraditionalAvgDouble", doubleArray, N);
std::cout << std::endl;
```

the second problem is that routines written in AVX2 are slower than routines written in cpp. The images represent the results of the two tests

[image: Result of the test 1]

[image: Result of the test 2]

How can I overcome this strange behavior? What is the reason behind it?

Comment: Try to disassemble the C compiler code, but I would hazard a guess that it doesn't use he assembly divide instruction, but just subtracts 1 from the exponent. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720668/fast-multiplication-division-by-2-for-floats-and-doubles-c-c

Comment: Likely that the optimizer in VS2017 simply was able to generate code that was more efficient than your manually crafted AVX stuff. It is a common problem to over-optimize stuff, and end up with something that is in fact slower. Can't you use the regular code and tell VS to use AVX2 instead? (compiler flag /arch:AVX2)

Comment: What's `int64_to_double_full`, and why are you using it on values zero-extended from `char`?  You only need to widen to 32-bit elements so you can use hardware `_mm256_cvtepi32_pd`.  Also, MSVC doesn't optimize intrinsics much if at all; it might not be optimizing `__m128d divider=_mm_set1_pd(2);` into a multiply or FMA by `0.5`.

Comment: Also, why is your scalar C obfuscated as `*ptrDouble = ((double)(*(vec1 + packIdx) + *(vec2 + packIdx)))/ ((double)2);` instead of `(vec1[packIdx] + vec2[packIdx]) / 2.0`?  Either way I'd expect that to auto-vectorize nicely to **integer addition** before widening to FP.

Answer (score 1):

MSVC doesn't optimize intrinsics (much), **so you get an actual `vdivpd` by `2.0`, not a multiply by `0.5`**.  That's a worse bottleneck than scalar, less than one element per clock cycle on most CPUs.  (e.g. Skylake / Ice Lake / Alder Lake-P: 4 cycle throughput for `vdivpd xmm`, or 8 cycles for `vdivpd ymm`, either way 2 cycles per element. https://uops.info)

From [Godbolt, with MSVC 19.33 `-O2 -arch:AVX2`](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGISdKuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIGYAzKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/tKp6Y4CIWGRLDFxibaY9kUMQgRMxATZPn4B1bWZDU0EJRHRsfFJCo3Nrbkdo739ZRXDAJS2qF7EyOwcAG6oeOgA1AAqxEz4dWIAggBqAOIA%2BnIMyAhNB6gAIitR9BBoDKN7Xj%2BeGAYX2TyaewAVJtMMguKQ9r9/oD0iDMGDnsQoTDkGYEehPvRIXsCV4vphzsRjgBPBFIggAoFo/ahBn0IwEBALPYmADsVg05z2wr2rL2Ch8rwZJgSbz2GhlAqFItJ5OJyQIxA%2BZPoPNlJMJFKpTGpipMgpFe34WIgKOBoNFgj2ySYyAA1gBJdCqPVyhUJCzO12e716tx7dnATmKnmWawu91e1TcvlKy2WyEarWG317KCq%2BgLCCQiA4rixwMJkPJitQ0uwsy1qtJhatgD0eYgBcwCzMCzNFvTwqz2vJ1nHAfNyuFfLeU/nvLngvniVCyG8WDDeBYLFZxFCADoEDLsFPtrs9lc7oDwcRXqP6JSaT8BMimQ7b9jYfDEa%2BGXbmURTEv1xfFDWJbsnxNOk/0ZVEHTFSNORTfkp0tNs23pTBVGSLEAIQp02BYEhqXOWh7TYQQLGpAhMAUXMEjMAdp1/P5aJwvD33RR0GSiGi6OUWJlGDXMzAAVgANj2DsuAk5jLXw7ixSrDxAWlfUkIQaS9j42iFEE4hhPdZi0JVcDnU1B9MFzSDjVNSdl0HYVbluFguDMAAOfZ8E2XZYhlN5XJYW4lAILhbmSdAID7EynKtEg80UlknWbUMAvlGNUp9GVwxUlZBBjcdLCy/s4tTUyhyYLwiD2VRy3SoLbloVATi8EK8HcjyoHpPYXLczy8EhBYy37ByWMtKqatURsGp3JqWvQNr0k67rYL6zrBuGhtRqVCr0ySoCIVCLBsv1f1driy0AHcEDoTAIGO7Cwz2DyULTId00e1QiqsMaPvTDDJtQWquGa3NGuQTZaOSLwPNuTBkjwCTJAgOqdr2/7Aeq4HprB2bgsh6HYfhxHkdRmK/v%2BkUMPWzz9jqiL9nS1lkduIhbm7W4qC8WhaFR0HUHRy6Ppp1zOvpsxGdzFnJDZ1AOcNLmeb53HBfkqnhSBkG8f1CGoYR4mEbwRj%2BaF8aPq11XwbmwmDbho2Tems2NecsW6ZBqX8duW3EcYxn%2Bea52XdprzaslyLrYJ/XffDqLVbN%2BdhaHRrRhITB/ZHQ0EUanz/cak50H9hnIoRabGaWEk8F8rBiFbdWNcznVrPSxvyVrJjKY1urI5C4hyPala6oRCn3q7mbdbmhQ%2B7wAfPPJ4eg6HWcMZFMsK3S3SBKE4N6/THEZrjfVN/07fjM7nlF0TljrUSrjkoZPA8FzDQ9UDR/ns02MxKDd1VIKgN16WEfqVFi5Uk51lbrqawoo8Apn1F2Q0RYSxr2gcA2syCGy1mAQsDsCCm69l3svRy5wiHnA4EsWgnAxK8D8BwLQpBUCcDcD9cUKw1jN0SDwUgBBNDkKWG6EACQEgHiEaIsR4iJL6E4JIGhvCGGcF4AoEAGhuG8KWHAWASA0AsERvQMgFAXw6LunEdchhgBcDEhoFRNBaC0WIEoiAUQ5FRFCE0aknAuHaMogQAA8gwWg7i6G8CwCwMx4ggmkHwMQWEjgYRKIidhWE1UNhcNZDUOR5EojHGINSDwWA5Gam3B48hfADDAAUJcPAmAro%2BOSIwYpMhBAiDEOwKQjT5BKDUHI3Q8IDBGBQD9fQeAohKMgEsVAGpMjxIALQ%2BISHsaZoS1jHllAoN01IDBumsoomoMTMguAYO4TwbQ9DBFCAMcoQx4QFAyAICYfhrlpFuQwWYgw4jwjsHsgQPRxjHNyB83ZDhuhjD6OcuYVzbAgvuXoaYzRXmXPeUsBQbD1h6E1JgFJJTKEcGoaQWh9DGEcFUB5CS0zkaIj6cAPYFiDwaFpXmZhcZLAIlwIQBK5gEg/g8EYvRsZOULF4DwoJrZSACKESI8RkqhGSOxTIvFcjCWKOUao4VpANGIBQKgHlsRyCUG0booYmxkDJGSLcTYXAACctwhG3FUMjPgdA7EOKcRElxzAckNK8YwXx/jAn0JCWEjY/q8DRKBXEuRiTkDJIaWk7F9DMnZNyRgINgr9wsGKUsKgZSKlVJqXU2hXD%2BBNNEOINpRaOkqHUBE3QeJKUDKZTYTJoyIDjMma%2BTgszGzTKaE8EAVwAAaZgdldGcBAVw0L4RnNKG8iQjEUhPLqBO%2BdhRMjwvmFwOdnygXfKhX8h5nQvn1BBWuq5lrIW9CXbC0F06EUSEtUilFrTuHRMxRQqhsiImErtZIPYLAFBGr2Oai1EqGWDL2KyogWIOVcq1QaqDiQ%2ByCrUfwwRwipVSqkRwOV%2BLeCKtsMqoVWgRXYqHfKz9CiVVEaWDCex%2BzJBAA%3D), with a version that compiles (replacing your undefined `int64_to_double_full` with efficient 32-bit conversion).  Your version is probably even worse.

```
$LL5@AVG_unchar:
        vpmovzxbd xmm0, xmm5
        vpmovzxbd xmm1, xmm4
        vcvtdq2pd xmm3, xmm0
        vcvtdq2pd xmm2, xmm1
        vaddpd  xmm0, xmm3, xmm2
        vdivpd  xmm3, xmm0, xmm6         ;; performance disaster
        vmovupd XMMWORD PTR [r8], xmm3
        add     r8, 16
        vpsrldq xmm4, xmm4, 2
        vpsrldq xmm5, xmm5, 2
        sub     rax, 1
        jne     SHORT $LL5@AVG_unchar
```

Also, AVX2 implies support for 256-bit integer as well as FP vectors, so you can use `__m256i`.  Although with this shift strategy for using the chars of a vector, you wouldn't want to.  You'd just want to use `__m256d`.

Look at how clang vectorizes the scalar C++: https://godbolt.org/z/Yzze98qnY 2x `vpmovzxbd`-load of __m128i / `vpaddd` __m128i / `vcvtdq2pd` to __m256d / `vmulpd` __m256d (by 0.5) / `vmovupd`.  (Narrow loads as a memory source for `vpmovzxbd` are good, especially with an XMM destination so they can micro-fuse on Intel CPUs.  Writing this with intrinsics relies on compilers optimizing `_mm_loadu_si32` into a memory source for `_mm_cvtepu8_epi32`.  Looping to use all bytes of a wider load isn't crazy, but costs more shuffles.  clang unrolls that loop, replacing later `vpsrldq` / `vpmovzxbd` with `vpshufb` shuffles to move bytes directly to where they're needed, at the cost of needing more constants.)

IDK what wrong with MSVC, why it failed to auto-vectorize with `-O2 -arch:AVX2`, but at least it optimized `/2.0` to `*0.5`.  When the reciprocal is exactly representable as a `double`, that's a well-known safe and valuable optimization.

With a good compiler, there'd be no need for intrinsics.  But "good" seems to only include clang; GCC makes a bit of a mess with converting vector widths.

---

Your scalar C is strangely obfuscated as `*ptrDouble = ((double)(*(vec1 + packIdx) + *(vec2 + packIdx)))/ ((double)2);` instead of
`(vec1[packIdx] + vec2[packIdx]) / 2.0`.

Doing **integer addition** like this scalar code before conversion to FP is a good idea, especially for a vectorized version, so there's only one conversion.  Each input already needs to get widened separately to 32-bit elements.

---

IDK what `int64_to_double_full` is, but if it's manual emulation of AVX-512 `vcvtqq2pd`, it makes no sense to use use it on values zero-extended from `char`.  That value-range fits comfortably in `int32_t`, so you can widen only to 32-bit elements, and let hardware int->FP packed conversion with [`_mm256_cvtepi32_pd`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,Other&ig_expand=1369,833,6404,660,6942&text=cvtdq2pd) (`vcvtdq2pd`) widen the elements.